# Can VPC's across Regions share Direct Connect Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-direct-connect

I am Referring to the following Architecture
[image]

So if VPC 10.1.0.0/16 and VPC 10.2.0.0/16 be in different location sharing the same Direct Connect Service?

Comment: Did you refer https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/

Comment: No not that one @KushVyas . I am referring to https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-single-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/ document.

Answer (score 3):

helloV's answer is 100% valid as of the time when it was written (Oct 30).

Just 2 days later, on November 1, 2017, AWS announced Direct Connect Gateway, a new feature to allow customers using any AWS Direct Connect Location to use their Direct Connect connections to access any Virtual Private Cloud deployed in any AWS Regions (except AWS China Region).

For more information see the news: [AWS Direct Connect Enables Global Access](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-direct-connect-enables-global-access/).

More details are available in AWS documentation: [Direct Connect Gateways User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/direct-connect-gateways.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Michal for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if all regions are in US. From: [AWS Direct Connect – Access to Multiple US Regions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-direct-connect-access-to-multiple-us-regions/)

You can provision a single connection to any Direct Connect location in the United States and use it to access all four of the AWS Regions in the US:

- (US East (Northern Virginia)
- US West (Northern California)
- US West (Oregon)
- AWS GovCloud (US)

The document was dated **19 DEC 2013**  when **US East (Ohio)** was not introduced. So multiple regions supported includes US East (Ohio) too.

Comment: Fine print, this appears to carry an additional cross-region transport charge of $0.03/GB back to the region where the Direct Connect connection is physically provisioned.